# String comparison not working in bash

Tags: bash, string

Simple string comparison is not working in bash. What's wrong with this :

```
$ cat compare.sh
function compare {

BEFORE_STATUS=enabled
AFTER_STATUS=disabled

if [ $BEFORE_STATUS = $AFTER_STATUS ]
then
   echo -e "1.  Before and after values not matching. PLEASE CHECK !!!!"
else
   echo -e "1.  Before and after values are matching. It is Ok."
fi
}

compare
```

After Execution:

```
$ sh compare.sh
1.  Before and after values are matching. It is Ok.
$
```

Comment: Are you serious?

Comment: You used the `bash` tag, but you gave a `.sh` extension to your file and called it with `sh` while it's actually more like `zsh` syntax btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is working as it is written.  Your `echo` statements in your `if` block are backwards.  The second should be first and the first should be second.  Either that or negate the `test` condition.